Can I have two Stripe webhook endpoints listening for the same event?
I am running into an issue since I have two webhook endpoints (/webhook/stripe and /webhook/stripe-connect) on the same server, and both listening for payment_intent.succeeded for different purposes.
Is there anyway to keep these webhooks on the same server, while both listening for the same event(s) and handling them differently?
All of my payment_intent events are getting handled by /webhook/stripe, even when some should be handled by /webhook/stripe-connect.

You should be able to listen to and handle same events for account and connect type webhooks separately. See: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/webhooks
There must be some misconfiguration on your end if your account webhook route is receiving connect events. You should double check your server configuration and validate the events being processed by both route to see if they're receiving the expected event types.
